# Is there a Https IO connector for Apache Beam?

Tags: java, https, apache-beam, connector, apache-beam-io

I want the outputs of my Beam pipeline (in Java) written into another server through Https, but I did not find any built-in connectors. I know it is possible to create a custom connector, but I want to know first if anything already exists.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton stated, there is no built-in support for HTTPS IO in Beam at this time. There has been some documentation on websocket which I'll include for reference.

However the standard approach for doing something like this is on a custom transform that uses a ParDo to write out each element to an endpoint.

Some reference material that can get you started is:

- **Websocket Implementation :** https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/apache-beam-websocket-output
- **Composite Transform :** https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-transforms
- **ParDo:** https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo

As a follow up iFeng also posted this question to the dev email group and here is a link to the follow up from developers there: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e082c02fc95354af5ccfc6d50aa9a08a2587c48c88d90e4f9272797b@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for HTTPS IO in Beam, here's a list of supported IOs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/